# Error en consulta

Tags: php, mysql

Buen dia, estoy haciendo una consulta en PHP para poder sacar los datos dependiendo la fecha de los registros, el detalle es que la consulta no me funciona, no estoy muy seguro de que la sintaxis de la consulta en la parte del WHERE este correcta ya que uso un INNER JOIN para obtener informacion de dos tablas, me podrian indicar si es correcta la consulta y de no ser asi me podrian decir en que parte me estoy equivocando. Anexo codigo:

```
$consulta = "SELECT empleado.nomina, empleado.nombre, empleado.depto, comentarios.comentario, comentarios.fecha FROM empleado WHERE fecha < '$fecha' INNER JOIN comentarios on empleado.nomina=comentarios.nomina";
```

Answer (score 0):

El `INNER JOIN` es parte de la clausula `FROM`, no debe ir en el `WHERE`. Hay varias maneras de estructurar una query para generar la interseccion de la tabla, en este momento puede que estes confundiendo dos de ellas:
Podemos hacerlo con un `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT empleado.nomina,
       empleado.nombre,
       empleado.depto,
       comentarios.comentario,
       comentarios.fecha
  FROM empleado    INNER JOIN 
       comentarios ON empleado.nomina=comentarios.nomina
 WHERE fecha < '$fecha';
```

La otra manera es generando un producto cartesiano y filtrando los rows con la clausula `WHERE`:

```
SELECT empleado.nomina,
       empleado.nombre,
       empleado.depto,
       comentarios.comentario,
       comentarios.fecha
  FROM empleado   , -- la coma produce un producto cartesiano entre ambas tablas
       comentarios
 WHERE empleado.nomina=comentarios.nomina --los registros se filtran en el where
       fecha < '$fecha';
```

Ambos estilos son validos, pero recomiendo que si usas uno te quedes con ese para todo el proyecto ser consistente, ademas de formatear mejor tu query, SQL es indiferente a los espacios en blanco pero las personas no y a veces se complica leer querys de una sola linea.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus comentarios, lo probare

Answer (score 0):

Con esta consulta obtienes el resultado que esperas el `INNER JOIN` va dentro de `FROM` con el `WHERE` puedes hacer filtros (condiciones)

```
SELECT e.nomina, 
    e.nombre, 
    e.depto, 
    c.comentario, 
    c.fecha 
        FROM empleado AS e
            INNER JOIN comentarios AS c ON e.nomina = c.nomina 
        WHERE c.fecha < '$fecha'
```

> Recomendación trata de utilizar alias en las consultas.